# Setting up SSL Certificate for Stripe (on Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https

I'm setting up Stripe on a Wordpress blog hosted on a Bluehost server. The Stripe account has been created and the widget added to Wordpress. Now I need HTTPS/SSL in order to make it work (I think). Where can I get a cheap/free SSL certificate that can easily be integrated via plugin or other generally straightforward method?

Answer (score 0):

[read this article](http://www.dylanbeattie.net/docs/openssl_iis_ssl_howto.html)

**It will help you for generate certificate**

after done this preocess every hosting website have installing ssl certificate option then you can use this file code or upload .cer file

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://cheapsslsecurity.com/. They will offer a Domain Validation SSL certificate for a very low price. Odds are you won't need a fancier certificate.  You should do a bit of research here to make sure though.

You will have to use your bluehost cpanel to generate a Certificate Signing Request as part of the steps of getting your certificate. Once you have your new certificate you will have to upload it to bluehost for your domain. Bluehost support will help you with these 2 steps if needed.

Once your SSL Certificate has been setup, you then need to configure your web page for accepting payment information to be secured. You can use the WordPress HTTPS (SSL) plugin for this (it still works despite not being updated in a while). https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/